# Changing text into textarea with JS but events are not fired

Tags: javascript, events, textarea, dom-events

I would like to change textarea value using JS as when I write with my keyboard but events are not fired (text is changed).

```
area.value = text;
area.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
area.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Maybe I need any event more? keypress? keydown? ...

How I could put the caret into textarea?

Comment: did you add an event listener to area?

Comment: Yes, when I write with my keyboard events are fired!

Comment: you might want to show that as well

Comment: I cant show that, it is not my webpage, and login is necessary

Comment: You’re aware that [`document.createEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) is deprecated? Have you tried using the [`Event` constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) instead? Also, Amparo, we don’t want to see your live page, we’re asking you to share the “*[mcve]*” code so that we can see what you’re doing in order to reproduce your problem in order that we can help.

Comment: It is not my webpage, and I dont know how I can get a minimal reproducible example. Sorry man. I can run console commands if you want.

Comment: I have used `area.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));` but the problem is the same

Comment: @ChrisLi I can see the event I need fire is 'input' event. How can do it?

Comment: I think webpage is programmed with React (React expects to hear the input event)